# Laravel 9+ symfony mailer update: new return type on Mailer - as well on queues?

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

reading here:

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/upgrade#symfony-mailer

I read:

**Updated Return Types**

> The send, html, raw, and plain methods on Illuminate\Mail\Mailer no longer return void. Instead, an instance of Illuminate\Mail\SentMessage is returned. This object contains an instance of Symfony\Component\Mailer\SentMessage that is accessible via the getSymfonySentMessage method or by dynamically invoking methods on the object.

SentMessage is only returned when it was sync e.g. no queue, right?

Im a bit confused:
symfonys own mailer interface does return void
https://github.com/symfony/mailer/blob/6.3/MailerInterface.php

symfonys transport does return a `SentMessage` which... I dont think is encouraged to use directly.

laravels Mailable does return a `SentMessage`

https://github.com/illuminate/mail/blob/master/Mailable.php#L196
https://github.com/illuminate/mail/blob/master/Mailer.php#L542

Does this only apply to sync emails in laravel?

what is the point of `SentMessage` ?

Comment: Yes, Mailable::send() (and the others) return SentMessage but Mailable::queue() does not. And even when SendQueuedMailable::handle calls Mailable::send() it doesn't return the SentMessage which is generated. What is the point of `SentMessage`? -- It looks to me like it can provide a way to get the 'Message-ID' header, which may be something that someone needs to log?